# Problems with performing image translation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-transform

I'm trying to do image translation using MATLAB, and the image doesn't move at all. My code is:

```
myPic = imread('pic.jpg');
x = 250;
y = 375;

trans = affine2d([1 0 0; 0 1 0; x y 1]);

outputPic = imwarp(myPic, trans);

imshow(myPic)
axis on
figure()
imshow(outputPic)
axis on
isequal(myPic,outputPic) %evaluates to 1!!!
```

When I do the same for a rotation affine matrix, it worked. Why doesn't this work?

here's what happens when I print both pics:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't work? How do you check that?

Comment: I check it because I understand the numbers on the axes for outputPic should be different than the ones for myPic. and yes,. axis on equal is matlab code

Comment: Can you show an example input/output?

Comment: I've added a sample of what happens and some more code to prove what happens

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work, you'll need to define an 'OutputView' parameter.
This parameter sets the size and location of the output image in world coordinate system, using [imref2d](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imref2d.html) function.

Example:

```
myPic = imread('peppers.png');
x = 250;
y = 375;

%defines transformations
trans = affine2d([1 0 0; 0 1 0; x y 1]);
eyeTrans= affine2d([1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]);

%initializes imref2d object
outView = imref2d([size(myPic,1)+y,size(myPic,2)+x]);

outputPic1 = imwarp(I,trans,'OutputView',outView)
outputPic2 = imwarp(I,eyeTrans,'OutputView',outView)

%display result
figure,
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(outputPic2); title('original')
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(outputPic1); title('translated')
```

Result:

[image]