# Changing the size of the matrix image when translating in Matlab

Tags: matlab, translation

I have DICOM images that I want to translate 2 mm to the left in the x-axis and 24 mm down in the y-axis.
I have the command for the translation: affine2d and imwarp. I have compared the two images before and after the translation. The translation image is drawn in the right place, but your MAtrix size is not the same as the image before the translation.
This is about translation and not about changing the MAtrix size.
Here is my code :

```
x=-2;
y=24;
T3 = [1 0 0;0 1 0; x y 1];
tform = affine2d(T3); 
for j1=1:512
  Sagittal_3D_CBCT_Trans4(:,:,j1)=imwarp(Sagittal_3D_CBCT2(:,:,j1), tform,'OutputView', imref2d(size(Sagittal_3D_CBCT2(:,:,j1)),Hoehe_des_Pixels_CT,1));
end
figure(1),subplot(1,2,1),imshow(Sagittal_3D_CBCT2 (:,:,q),[]),,axis on,axis tight,subplot(1,2,2),imshow(Sagittal_3D_CBCT_Trans4(:,:,q),[]),axis on,axis tight
```

The following images show the difference before (left) and after tranlation (right). I have drawn this red line to show you the difference.

[image]

I ask you for a solution to my problem and I am very grateful for it.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484718/problems-with-performing-image-translation-in-matlab

Comment: and this : https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/perform-a-2-d-translation-transformation.html